# PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form I want to submit via PHP and following submission I want to write some HTML to the browser so that the user has some feedback.  There is a series of the same form on the page, each with a unique ID. The HTML is written to a div with a class of the specific ID.

I have an `onClick` function on my form and I can get the form to either submit or write the HTML, but not both.  I'm wondering if I'm trying to do two conflicting things.  Here is the JS function:

```
function requestQuote(id) {
    $('.' + id + '-quote').html('<div style="line-height:12px; font-size:11px; padding:5px;"><strong>Your quote has been submitted.</strong> A Universal expert will be in touch shortly.</div> <input type="submit" name="" value="Request a Quote" onClick="requestQuote(' + id + ');" id="' + id + '"  />');
    this.form.submit();
}
```

If I put the form submission before the HTML, the HTML is not excuted.  I don't think I should even  have to have the second line, but something is conflicting somewhere.

Comment: You have an onclick event defined, or an onsubmit event?  Maybe an onsubmit event would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use ajax.

because if you dont, as soon as the form submits, you are off the page and a user cannot see what you are displaying.

link for [jquery](http://jquery.com/)
link for [jquery and ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

Comment: OK.  Except my form doesn't submit and wipe out the data, it just refuses to submit with the HTML line above.  Can you get me started on the AJAX or point me toward a resource?

Comment: you can use jquery's library and ajax.

Comment: i added some resources above for your use

Comment: no prob. now accept some answers on this question and ur other questions and more people would want to help ^_^

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).form.submit()`  is the correct syntax, I believe.  If not, call the form by id.

Comment: $('.' + id + '-quote').html('...')  looks like jquery to me.

Answer (score 0):

You would use something like:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){

var id = 'id of your response div';

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/url/to/phpscript',
data: $('form').serialize(),
success: function(data){
    $('.' + id + '-quote').html('<div style="line-height:12px; font-size:11px; padding:5px;"><strong>Your quote has been submitted.</strong> A Universal expert will be in touch shortly.</div> <input type="submit" name="" value="Request a Quote" onClick="requestQuote(' + id + ');" id="' + id + '"  />');

}
});
```

Comment: Is the data posted in a serialized way?  So I use unserialize in PHP to deconstruct it?